# Why are db collections created for Mongoose 6 subdocs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm looking at upgrading my projects mongoose version from 5.10.19 to latest (6.5.1). I'm noticing that I have a lot more collections in my database than I did before. I made a simple example to test this out and when I run it on mongoose 5, I only see the collection "mains" but mongoose 6 creates "mains" and "subs". I'd expect that the subdocument models would not have their own collection like mongoose 5 behaves.

```js
import { connect, model, Schema } from 'mongoose';

const mongoUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

(async () => {
  const subSchema: Schema = new Schema({ color: String, yes: Boolean });
  const mainSchema: Schema = new Schema({ name: String, sub: subSchema });

  const MainModel = model('Main', mainSchema);
  model('Sub', subSchema);

  await connect(mongoUrl, { ssl: true, sslValidate: false });
  console.log(`Successfully connected to mongodb: "${mongoUrl}"`);

  await MainModel.create({ name: 'One', sub: { color: 'Yellow', yes: true } });
})()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('\nSuccess');
    process.exit();
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('\nFailure');
    process.exit();
  });
```

Is there a mongoose setting I'm missing that's causing this to happen?

Also, on Node 12.20.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because of [this change](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#autocreate-defaults-to-true):

> `autoCreate` is `true` by default unless readPreference is secondary or secondaryPreferred, which means Mongoose will attempt to create every model's underlying collection before creating indexes.

So turning off [`autoCreate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#autoCreate) (and possibly `autoIndex`) on `subSchema` should fix it. Alternatively, just don't create a model of it (only the schema).